# Affordable and compatible usb wifi adapter

Tags: networking, wifi, hardware, raspi-config, kali

I run kali linux in my raspberry pi 3 model B. I know that alfa makes some of the best cards and that Atheros is the best for ethical hacking and packet injection. But I just wanted to know if there are any cheaper yet decent options available.

Thanks for your time and I appreciate all the help i can get.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a shopping recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the onboard wireless.

See https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon 
or just grab a Kali Rolling image from : https://github.com/nethunteros/rpi3-kalimon/releases

HTH

Comment: I used the github link suggested by you but I can't decide which one to use..........1)Build patches for bcm4330, bcm4339 and bcm4358 using a x86 computer running Linux (e.g. Ubuntu 16.04) or 2)Build patches for bcm43438 on the RPI3 using Raspbian 8 (recommended).  Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to try out the nethunter image and then decide. Building took quite awhile on RPi0w.

Comment: I downloaded the nexmon kali linux image for raspberry pi 3 and it works well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Please mark it as the answer :)

Comment: I'm new here but I think it's the green tick